# Moving a sublist of items in a list to a new position

Tags: python, algorithm, list

I have grappled with this problem for some time now, and googled extensively, but have never come up with a satisfactory, clean solution. The problem seems simple enough and a solution always seems tantalizingly close, but so far it has eluded me.

### The problem

Consider a list of items, indexed from 0, stored remotely. The size of the list is not known (or not important), and the only way to reorder items in the list is to move them, one by one, from a source index to a destination index using commands of the form:

```
moveitem(from_index, to_index)
```

which, for list *lst*, is conceptually equivalent to the Python:

```
lst.insert(to_index, lst.pop(from_index))
```

The task is to write a function

```
moveitems(from_indices, to_index)
```

which, given:

- *from_indices* - a list of item indices, and
- *to_index* - a target index

generates a sequence of *moveitem(from_index, to_index)* instructions which move the items at the indicated indices to the target position in the list, retaining the order in which the indices are listed in *from_indices*.

If the remote list is *lst*, then the net effect of calling *moveitems(from_indices, to_index)* should be the equivalent of the following Python expression (**expr1**):

```
[x for x in lst[:to_index] if x not in from_indices] +
from_indices +
[x for x in lst[to_index:] if x not in from_indices]
```

Or, given the following definition of list difference:

```
diff = lambda l1, l2: [x for x in l1 if x not in l2]
```

the desired result is (**expr2**):

```
diff(lst[:to_index], from_indices) +
from_indices +
diff(lst[to_index:], from_indices)
```

Thus, if the remote list contained items:

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12, ... ]
```

a call to *moveitems([8, 2, 7, 4, 0], 6)* should transform it to:

```
[1, 3, 5, 8, 2, 7, 4, 0, 6, 9, 10, 11, 12, ... ]
```

with the following - or equivalent - sequence of move instructions:

```
moveitem(0,5)
moveitem(3,4)
moveitem(7,4)
moveitem(1,3)
moveitem(8,3)
```

Note that in the above example the items are being moved in the reverse order they appear in the list of indices (*from_indices*). This is acceptable, as long as the order in which items are listed in *from_indices* is preserved in the transformed list.

The problem is how to compute the sequence of move instructions, keeping track of list indices as they change with successive extraction and insertion of items.

### A solution of sorts

Currently, the solution I'm using looks like this (in Python):

```
def moveitems(from_indices, to_index):

    lst_len = max(from_indices + [to_index])+1
    lst = list(range(lst_len))

    last = to_index
    for item in from_indices[::-1]:
        source = lst.index(item)
        dest = lst.index(last)
        if dest > source: dest -= 1
        lst.insert(dest, lst.pop(source))
        last = item
        moveitem(source, dest)
```

It starts off by constructing a list of indices *lst = [0,1,2,3,4,...]*. We have no idea of the length of the remote list, but it must be at least as long as the maximum index which appears in the list *from_indices* and the index *to_index*.

We then iterate through the items to be moved (*from_indices*) - each time, *item* is the item to be moved and *last* is the previously moved item. The idea is to pop the item from wherever it is in the list and insert it next to the last moved item. Since a list insertion in Python inserts items BEFORE the item currently at the point of insertion, we iterate through *from_indices* in reverse order. We search for *item* and *last* in the list *lst* to obtain their positions *source* and *dest*, and then pop the *item* from position *source* and insert it before the previously moved item at position *dest*. A small correction is necessary when the destination is higher than the source, to compensate for the destination shifting down by 1 when *source* is popped.

This solution works - in the sense that it produces a list equivaent to that produced by (**expr1**) and (**expr2**) above - but has 3 major problems:

- It is ugly;
- it is ugly; and
- it is impractical for large indices.

Because the algorithm constructs a temporary list of indices as long as the maximum index of interest, even moving a few items in a largish list would incur considerable space and time overheards. Just consider something like:

```
moveitems([56, 12, 19], 1000000)
```

### Challenge

I'm looking for an algorithm which computes the required sequence of *moveitem* instructions directly, correctly keeping track of the indices as they change when items are moved about without needing to manipulate and repeatedly search a (possibly very big) temporary list of indices. Bonus points if the algorithm moves the items in the same order they are listed in the list *from_indices*.

### Context

The items represent documents on a remote server. Users can browse the list, select a random sublist of documents, and then drag them to a new position in the list. The client must then send a sequence of *moveitem* instructions to the server to reorder the list accordingly. The documents must retain the order they were selected in (NOT their original order).

Comment: Seems I can't wrap my brain around the problem formulation. Doesn't `[x for x in lst[:to_index] if x not in from_indices]` actually mix list elements with index numbers? Didn't you want to write `[x for x in range(0,to_index) if x not in from_indices]`?

Comment: We are not directly interested in the items themselves, only in how the items at those indices move about when we pop and insert other items. So, a list of indices such as [0,1,2] represents items in another list, for example ['A','B','C']. If we then pop C ad insert it at index 0, getting ['C','A','B'], the state of the list now, in comparison to its original state, can be represented by the indices [2,0,1].

Comment: Yeah, ok, but that only works for the first action, afterwards your list of indices is unsorted, and you can't ask for `x not in from_indices` etc. because the `from_indices` are indices to your indices - unless I completely don't grok how that selection of to-move items is generated.

Comment: Just think of it as manipulating the indices instead of the items themselves.

Comment: As I said, your list of indices is good for one manipulation (the user can move items once), after that you need to enumerate the presented list anew. Your `moveitems` function doesn't need `lst[]` as input. That was what I had a problem of understanding. Or, put another way, after the first exchange the list is `[1, 3, 5, 8, 2, 7, 4, 0, 6, 9, 10, 11, 12, ... ]`. How does the user invoke another exchange? She is seeing elements 1,3,5,8 as the first 4 on her display.

Comment: Hi Vroomfondel, the indices are only required for one manipulation - they represent the input to the algorithm, telling it which items in a list need moving and where to take them. The algorithm then generates the required sequence of move instructions, each instruction moving one item in the list. At the end of the process, the list has been updated and the indices are no longer required. Hope that helps.

Comment: This means that you don't need `lst[]` after the operation, so you could get rid of the complicated tracking of indices alltogether and instead write a new list where the indices have assumed their correct position - unless you need the `move()` operations outside of Python for e.g. a database operation.

Comment: Yes, the list *lst* is only temporary, used to track the location of the various items being shifted as insertions and deletions are made. The whole point of the exercise is to compute the move instructions - as I said, they are sent to a remote document server which uses them to re-order the REAL list, each instruction moving one document from its current location in the list to a new location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider `I` the item to move, `J` the next adjacent item and `N` your target `idx`

Two cases:

- case 1: item is before `N`

```
    I|J| | | |N
    J| | | |N|I
```

All your elements between `I+1` and `N` (included) are translated to the left

- case 2: item is after `N`

```
    N| | | |I|J
    N|I| | | |J
```

All the elements between `N+1` and `I-1` are translated to the right.

At this point an **approximate** pseudocode (about the indices) looks like:

```
while el = L.pop()
    moveItem(el, N)
    if el < N
        for all indices of L > el and el < N
            indices--
    else
        for all indices of L < el and > N
            indices++
    N+=1 #target our last elem
```

---

Below a (supposed) proper implem

```
def move_item(lst, src, dst):
    print('move ', src, dst)
    el = lst.pop(src)
    lst.insert(dst, el)

def move_items(arr, indices, N):
    while(len(indices)):
        el = indices.pop(0)
        if el == N:
            #our elem is in place
            #target is the elem after
            N += 1
            continue

        if el < N:
            #pop effect
            N -=1

            #insert the elem after N (
            move_item(arr, el, N)
            for j in range(len(indices)):
                el2 = indices[j]
                if el2 > el and el2 <= N:
                    indices[j] -= 1
        else:
            move_item(arr, el, N)
            for j in range(len(indices)):
                el2 = indices[j]
                if el2 > N and el2 < el:
                    indices[j] += 1

        #we have inserted an elem after N
        #next target is our last elem
        N += 1
        print('now', arr, 'indices', indices)


move_items([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12], [8,2,7,4,0],6)    #[1, 3, 5, 8, 2, 7, 4, 0, 6, 9, 10, 11, 12]
move_items([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12], [8,2,7,4,0,10],6) #[1, 3, 5, 8, 2, 7, 4, 0, 10, 6, 9, 11, 12]
move_items([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12], [1,10,5,7,3,8],6) #[0, 2, 3, 4, 1, 10, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12]
```

Comment: Thanks for this, and for correcting the slight bug in the original version. It seems to work great - will test it more thoroughly later on, especially on edge cases (where most of the fun is!), but for now I'm voting this as the best answer. Much appreciated!

Comment: I have done some testing on this, and the only problem I can see is that it does not respect the semantics of the Python list insert, which inserts the new item to the LEFT (i.e. BEFORE) the item at the insertion point. This algorithm inserts it AFTER, so move_item([2],0) produces the list [0,2,1,...] instead of [2,0,1,...]. This is easy to correct - the N+1 in the two calls to move_item should be N.

Comment: @mkam thx for notifying and suggesting fix. I actually wanted to simply N-=1 at beginning of algo but this leads to an invalid result for [1,10,5] (which needs to make a right bound of <= N+1 to be fixed). I am somehow uncomfortable with this right bound so I went for your suggestion. Not sure if a configuration could invalidate your suggestion as well

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to user753642 for the answer above. I have rewritten his algorithm to use the same symbolic names as the original question, and made the coding slightly more Pythonic. I have omitted all comments, as his explanation is excellent and his code is well documented.

```
def moveitems(from_indices, to_index):

    while from_indices:
        el = from_indices.pop(0)
        if el != to_index:
            if el < to_index: to_index -=1

            moveitem(el,to_index)
            for i in range(len(from_indices)):
                el2 = from_indices[i]
                if (el < to_index) and (el2 > el) and (el2 <= to_index):
                    from_indices[i] -= 1
                elif (el > to_index) and (el2 > to_index) and (el2 < el):
                    from_indices[i] += 1

        to_index += 1
```